# force:navigateToSObject's slideDevName doesn't support in API Version > 37

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, navigation

If you goto this link

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.202.0.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_navigateToSObject.htm

slideDevName - Supported for lightning experience for API 37. It is mentioned in API 37 documentation.

But In API 40 it is saying like 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_navigateToSObject.htm

> This attribute has no effect in Lightning Experience.

Even I tied to use slideDevName = Detail page.

But is not redirecting to the Detail Page tab. It is just redirecting to the first tab in detail page of an object.

Any solution?

Comment: I have readjusted the default landing tab to detail tab in the lightning app builder, i had similar issue with force:refreshview and had to do the above approach.

Comment: yes, even we are doing the same now

Comment: I wish there was a navigatetoview component, even with the slidedevname option you can only set the redirect to standard page tabs(assuming it worked) I have custom page tabs where i would want to redirect user on form submit.